# Proving that $\{a\in\mathbb{Q}|a>0$ and $a^2<2\}$ has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am going through a proof found in: [http://www.math.columbia.edu/~harris/2000/2016Dedcuts.pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Eharris/2000/2016Dedcuts.pdf)

In it he finds a smaller upper bound to the supposed least upper bound: [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id4lU.png)

However in Step 1, I don't understand how the proof goes from $4\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}$ to it being less than
$4\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}$, it reasons that $\frac{1}{n^2}≤\frac{1}{n}$ but shouldn't that mean subtracting the larger number makes the result smaller than if i were to subtract the smaller number>?
i.e. $x<y$ then $z-x>z-y$ right? But here its saying that $z-y>z-x$

If it is a typo, can the proof still be salvaged?

Comment: The proof has a mistake.

Comment: Are you referring to the same portion of the proof, can it still be salvaged?

Comment: Yes, just find a $n$ with $r^2-2>4/n$.

Comment: You can replace inequality $2r/n-1/n^2<r^2-2$ (say $A$) with another $2r/n<r^2-2$ (say $B$). Why is this replacement valid? Because $B$ implies $A$. You can now find a desired value of $n$. Also observe that for such replacement we __don't__ need $A\implies B$.

Answer (score 1):

write $r = \frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms, meaning $p,q$  are positive integers  and $\gcd(p,q)=1.$  Note $p^2 - 2 q^2 > 0$  and name $k = p^2 - 2 q^2 > 0$

Make the new rational number
$$  s = \frac{3p+4q}{2p+ 3q} $$

We calculate $$ (3p+4q)^2 - 2 (2p+3q)^2 = p^2 - 2 q^2 = k   $$
but $s$  has a larger denominator.

As to the relative size of the fractions,
$$  \frac{p^2}{q^2} = \frac{k+ 2q^2}{q^2}  =  2  + \frac{k}{q^2} $$

But then
$$  \frac{(3p+4q)^2}{(2p+3q)^2} = \frac{k+ 2(2p+3q)^2}{(2p+3q)^2}  =  2  + \frac{k}{(2p+3q)^2} $$
is smaller  because $2p+3q > q$

Comment: The asker is trying to make sure that there is a typo or mistake in the proof they are studying. I don't think they want another different proof but are probably interested in fixing the proof referred in their question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, that would be preferred